# How to setup ACL on my S3 bucket for the simple, basic operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

I'm using S3 to store my backups. I'm doing that via `aws s3` and cron.

And the moment my bucket is public.

I want to setup ACL in such a way that only I may do CRUD + ListAll operations on it and that's it. I've read their documentation but it's too complicated whereas I need a simple thing. How can I do this?

1. my bash script on my VPS server should have access to the S3 bucket via API; probably there must also be a restriction by IP
2. I should have to my bucket via web console/S3 website from any place and any IP
3. the bucket shouldn't be accessible for no one else

Comment: You should at least consider restricting access to your bucket from your own source IP (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3) until you've worked out how to use credentials. Personally, I would consider using something like duplicati to perform backups, in which case it will explain to you how to create the necessary IAM credentials.

Comment: @jarmod, if I create a restriction by ip, will I able to access my bucket from any place via S3 web site? Is a restriction by ip only for API access?

Comment: If the policy says Allow and has an IpAddress condition, then yes you can access the bucket from the AWS console from a different IP (assuming the console user has the relevant S3 permissions, of course). The bucket policy is allowing you to access the bucket from your home IP. When you use the AWS console from a different IP, it's the policy associated with the logged-in user that gives you access to the bucket. Your effective policy is the least-privilege union of the two policies. If, however, your bucket policy was Deny with a NotIpAddress condition, then you could not do it.

Comment: @jarmod, then that won't work for me as I don't want to access my S3 web console **only** from a single IP address. I go to a coffee shop and what? I have no access. I go to other city - I have no access. I use mobile - I have no access. What'll be the point of that?

Comment: @jarmod -- `assuming the console user has the relevant S3 permissions, of course` -- how to allow this?

Comment: The combination of S3 bucket policies and IAM policies can be complex if you don’t understand them well. If you create an IP restriction using Allow/IpAddress, then this will work for you. If you create it with Deny/NotIpAddress then it will not work for you. No, this has nothing to do with APIs vs the console.

Comment: @jarmod, again: is an IP restriction applied only to API? Or to the S3 website/console as well?

Comment: What you are calling an “IP restriction” is an S3 bucket policy for unauthenticated access to your bucket from a specific IP. You can also have an IAM policy that allows authenticated access to your bucket from any IP.  The first of those 2 policies (the conditional bucket policy) is what allows you to access the bucket unauthenticated from your home IP. The second of those policies (the IAM policy) is what allows you (an IAM user) to access the bucket from the AWS Console while at Starbucks. My advice to you: always authenticate; do not leave the bucket publicly accessible; learn IAM.

Comment: @jarmod, you're explaining things even more difficult than they're written in aws documentation. I need a simple answer. you may post your answer.

Comment: You should use IAM to create credentials for your bucket and then only use those credentials to access your bucket programatically (like via the cron), and hten use the AWS console otherwise.

Comment: @bryan60, what's IAM?

Comment: Identity & Access Management. It is the primary method of securing cloud resources on AWS.  Cloud security is not a "simple thing" and takes time to learn to do right.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an S3 bucket policy so that only your PUBLIC IP address can access your bucket.

Here is an example policy. Change the bucket name to your bucket name. Change the IP address to your public IP address:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action":["s3:*"]  ,
            "Resource": [
                     "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",                         
                     "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"],
            "Condition" : {
                "IpAddress" : {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "192.168.143.0/32" 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    ]
}
```

1. Open the Amazon S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/.
2. Select the bucket that you want to attach the above policy.
3. Choose Permissions.
4. Choose Edit Bucket Policy.
5. Copy the above policy into the Bucket Policy Editor window.
6. Substitute the values (bucket name, IP address) in the bucket policy.
7. Choose Save and then Close.

Comment: if I create a restriction by ip, will I able to access my bucket from any place via S3 **web site**? Is a restriction by ip only for API access? in other words `PUBLIC IP address can access your bucket` --> is this applied to API access only?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you assign an S3 Bucket Policy that restricts access to only certain IP addresses, then only those IP addresses will be able to access the bucket. The exception is API based access where the credentials of the IAM User determines access.

Comment: 1) my bash script on my VPS server should have access to the S3 bucket via API; probably there must **also** be a restriction by IP  2) I should have to my bucket via **web console/S3 website** from **any place and any IP** 3) the bucket shouldn't be accessible for no one else

Answer (score 0):

You're using the AWS command line tool (awscli) to sync files to S3. You are presumably supplying credentials to awscli (very few people use the awscli unauthenticated).

So, assuming that you are authenticated, why have you made your S3 bucket public? The correct thing to do here is to ensure that the credentials you are using are associated with an IAM policy that allows you to access the S3 bucket. Then remove the S3 bucket policy.

If, for some reason, you really do want to be able to access the S3 bucket without authentication (not a good idea, generally) then you can make things somewhat safer by [applying a bucket policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3) allowing that level of access from *only* your IP address.

Hope this helps.